# convergence of the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^{\alpha}}}{n!} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^{\alpha}}}{n!} $ 
I need to determine for every $ \alpha \in R $ $ (\alpha > 0) $ if the series connverges or diverges. i already manged to show that for every $ \alpha \leq 1 $ the series converges. but i have any idea for the case $ \alpha > 1$ thanks.

Comment: As I've proven it below, the series converges even if $ \alpha=2 $, or $ \alpha=\frac{3}{2} $ for example. In fact, it does converge for every $ \alpha\leq 2 \cdot $

Comment: consider  Stirling's approximation  $n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ \alpha> 2 $, we have, for every positive integer $ n $, the following : $$ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^{\alpha}}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}\right)^{\frac{n^{\alpha}}{n+1}}\geq\mathrm{e}^{\frac{n^{\alpha}}{n+1}} $$

Note that for any $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, we have : \begin{aligned} \ln{n!}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\ln{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\int_{k}^{k+1}{\ln{k}\,\mathrm{d}x}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\int_{k}^{k+1}{\ln{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}}&=\int_{1}^{n+1}{\ln{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\&=\left(n+1\right)\ln{\left(n+1\right)}-n \end{aligned}

Thus : $$ \small\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{n^{\alpha}}{n+1}}}{n!}\geq \exp{\left(\frac{n^{\alpha}}{n+1}-\left(n+1\right)\ln{\left(n+1\right)}+n\right)}=\exp{\left(n^{\alpha -1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{\ln{\left(1+n\right)}}{n^{\alpha -2}}+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha-2}}\right)\right)}$$
Note that $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{\ln{\left(1+n\right)}}{n^{\alpha-2}}}=0 $, because the logarithm grow slower than any positive power of $ n $, that leads to $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\left(\frac{n}{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{\ln{\left(1+n\right)}}{n^{\alpha -2}}+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha-2}}\right)}=1 $, meaning : $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}{\exp{\left(n^{\alpha -1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{\ln{\left(1+n\right)}}{n^{\alpha -2}}+\frac{1}{n^{\alpha-2}}\right)\right)}}=+\infty $$
Thus, our series diverges, because its general term doesn't tend to $ 0 $, in fact it blows up to $ +\infty \cdot $

Let $ \alpha \leq 2 $, as we've done before : $$ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^{\alpha}}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^{n^{\alpha-1}}\leq\mathrm{e}^{n^{\alpha -1}} $$

And since $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \frac{\mathrm{e}^{n^{\alpha-1}}}{n!}\leq\frac{\mathrm{e}^{n}}{n!} $, we have that $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 0}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{n^{\alpha-1}}}{n!}} $ converges.

Hence, by comparaison test, our series converges in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately im not familier with those tools, taking approx of $ (1+(1)/n)^n $ and calculating the math on another series. Im not allowed to use such things because we havent proved those ways in class. Do you know any other way ? Thank you.

Comment: consider  Stirling's approximation  $n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}.$ you will find something.

Comment: @Waizman I did just use the comparaison test. Are you telling me that you were asked to solve this problem without having studied the comparison test yet ?

Comment: @CHAMSI im familier with the comparaison test. but you used the approx of n! (stirling's), we are not allowed to use it in our homework (since we havent proved it yet). you think it'll be complicated trying to prove it myself?

Comment: @Waizman I didn't use any $ n! $ approximation. It was not I who suggested that you use Stirling's approximation. Read my answer again.

Comment: @CHAMSI the only think i couldnt understand is this: $ lnn!=∑k=1nlnk=∑k=1n∫k+1klnkdx≤∑k=1n∫k+1klnxdx=∫n+11lnxdx=(n+1)ln(n+1)−n $ but i managed to figure it out now. thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, ok, I did just some comparaison, since the $ x $ is in $ \left[k,k+1\right] $, we have $ \ln{k}\leq\ln{x} $, and thus $ \int\limits_{k}^{k+1}{\ln{k}\,\mathrm{d}x}\leq\int\limits_{k}^{k+1}{\ln{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} $.